# Parameterization for complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am taking a complex analysis class and am struggling to understand how to come up with a parameterization. I am supposed to compute Compute the integral

$$\int_\gamma \bar z dz, $$

where $\gamma$ is the circle $| z |= 2$ traversed once counterclockwise. I don't want the answer, I just want to understand how to figure out the parameterization to figure out this problem.

Comment: Havent you talked in class how to parametrize paths?

Comment: It will help to write $z$ in polar form i.e. $z=re^{i\phi}$. What values do $r$ and $\phi$ take on along $\gamma$?

Comment: no, Im taking an online course. I am teaching these concepts to myself.

Comment: If I write z in polar form, I would have the conjugate of re^i(theta). I know that r=2 in this problem but when I try to take the integral of this, I am left with an e. I was wondering if I could use the fact that the conjugate of z= |z| squared divided by z. Then from here, put in the polar form, and use u substitution to calculate. This makes the e go away and then can calculate from 0 to 2 pi. Am I on the right track or way off?

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a circle of radius $r$ around a point $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$ traveled counterclockwise is given by the equation:
$$
\gamma(t) = (r\cos t, r\sin t) + z_0, \,\,t\in[0,2\pi).
$$
Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are so similar (they are isometric normed spaces), we can transform this curve into a curve in the complex plane using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula), from which we get that the same circle, now in the complex plane, is given by:
$$
\gamma(t) = r(\cos t + i\sin t) +z_0 = re^{it} + z_0, \,\,t\in[0,2\pi).
$$
In your particular case, the equation of the curve you want is given by $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$, so your integral becomes:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\overline{\left(2e^{it}\right)}\left(2e^{it}\right)'dt = 4\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}ie^{it}dt = 8\pi i.
$$